# Changing the data of the RowNode object of a field that is hidden

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

So according to the docs, ICellRendererParams provides access to the row node.

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/#reference-ICellRendererParams

I have a Cell renderer that receives some data. The data field of the row node of the CellRenderer (so props.node.data)

```
data: Object { id: 9548, nume: "ALBA IULIA", judet: {…} }
​​
id: 9548
​​
judet: Object { id: 43, nume: "BRASOV" }
​​
nume: "ALBA IULIA"
```

Now, my cell renderer is a dropdown which has to change judet.id.

I tried to change it this way: (inside my change handler)

```
props.node.setDataValue('judet.id', **any value in here**);
```

but I don't have a judet.id field inside my columnDefs object so I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: column is null
    getValue ag-grid-community.cjs.js:43208
    setDataValue ag-grid-community.cjs.js:15556
    handleChange SelectCellRenderer.tsx:43
    React 15
2 ag-grid-community.cjs.js:43208
    getValue ag-grid-community.cjs.js:43208
    setDataValue ag-grid-community.cjs.js:15556
    handleChange SelectCellRenderer.tsx:43
    React 15
    bind_applyFunctionN self-hosted:1349
    dispatchDiscreteEvent self-hosted:1312
    receiveMessage SelectChild.jsm:272
    receiveMessage SelectChild.jsm:475
```

if I add a field named 'judet.id', the error disappears and the value changes. But now I'm stuck with a column I don't want.

So, my question is:

is there any way to change the data of the row node if it doesn't have a column with that field? I looked into the ag-grid code and it looks to me that setDataValue call getColDefs, so setDataValue only works with fields that are defined as columns.

I didn't include a code example because I felt like this question is more theoretical.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `rowNode.setDataValue()` works only for defined columns, as it expects a `columnId` as parameter.
In your case you should use `rowNode.setData()`, see https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/data-update-single-row-cell/#reference-rowNodeMethods-setData

```
oldData: Object { id: 9548, nume: "ALBA IULIA", judet: {…} }
newJudet: Object { id: 43, nume: "BRASOV" }

rowNode.setData({...oldData, judet: newJudet})
```